# Java 9 on Windows with large fonts

Tags: java, swing, dpi, java-9

If you set large fonts (for example, 125%, 120 DPI) on Windows, then it looks as if Swing of Java 9 first renders into a smaller image and then scales this image to the screen.

Text is still properly displayed. But 1 pixel lines are times 1 pixel or 2 pixels strong. A diagonal line is stepped. Icons are rasterized.

Are there any command line parameters or API to change this behavior?

---

Example Edit:

Using `MenuSelectionManagerDemo` from [docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/)

[image]

Comment: please the printsceen and SSCCE / MCVE can help us

Comment: Is this behavior only with Java 9? I had no such problems with Java 7/8.

Comment: Yes, this problem occur only with Java 9.

Comment: Have you tried to restart the OS after the dpi change?

Comment: @wzberger The behavior does not change after a reboot.

Comment: Which Windows version do you use?

Comment: It's worth noting that the Oracle demo you ran now comes with a caveat. From your link: "The Java Tutorials have been written for JDK 8. Examples and practices described in this page don't take advantage of improvements introduced in later releases".

Comment: Also, it looks like Oracle have fixed the issue you raised: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8174845

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran that Swing **MenuSelectionManagerDemo** using Java 9 and Windows 10, and the issues you raised appear to be resolved. See the two screen shots below, where I ran with scaling set to 100% and 125% respectively.

As I pointed out in a comment to the OP, it looks like this was resolved by a JDK bug fix several months ago, which I assume was raised by the OP:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8174845

One other minor point worth noting is that changing the Windows setting from 100% to 125% is a change to "Scale and Layout", and will "Change the size of text, **apps and other items**". (i.e. It is far more than just a font change, as mentioned in the JDK bug response.)

[image: 100%]

[image: 125%]

Answer (score 3):

I found that on Oracle Java 9,10,11,12 and Amazon Corretto Java LTS (jdk 11.0.2_9) and the rasterization problem with icons/pictures are still a valid case and not fixed! Is this bugfix merged to trunk really?

Last version where this problem is not occurred is Java 8.0_202 where still everything goes well.

Comment: Was your platform Windows 10? If so that is strange, because the issue was definitely resolved for me as shown in [my answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46481274/2985643) on Windows 10 using Java 9.

Comment: HI! Yes it was a Windows 10 environment.